# Openshift v3 manual deployment

Tags: openshift, redhat

I was happy with the Openshift V2 because I was able to manually deploy my war file through filezilla and a manual start/stop using rhc tool. But, after I have created new account in v3, I cant seem to find any documentation on manual deployment.

Can somebody help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you likely want is called a binary input build. See:

- https://blog.openshift.com/binary-input-sources-openshift-3-2/
- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#binary-source